# TCPDF class not found in CPANEL. Works fine locally

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, classnotfoundexception, tcpdf

I followed a YouTube tutorial to deploy my Laravel project on a subdomain in cPanel. Initially, I zipped and uploaded the project successfully, and the website can be accessed. However, when I tried to update it with a new zip file upload which contains TCPDF library, it didn't work, and I couldn't find the best way to resolve the issue. Now,in cpanel, Laravel cannot find the tcpdf class, but it works locally.

Down here is my GenerateController code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Generate;
use App\Models\Header;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use TCPDF;



class GenerateController extends Controller
{
    
    //method for laravel auth
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    //method to return view/blade file
    public function pdfgen()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $data = $user->generates()->paginate(5);
        $headersData = $user->headers;

        return view('obj.pdfgen', [
            'data' => $data,
            'headerData' => $headersData,
        ]);
    }

    

    public function fillPDF()
    {
        $headersData = Header::All();
        // Retrieve the authenticated user object from the currently logged-in user
        $user = Auth::user();
        // Retrieve the "generates" relationship data for the user and paginate it (3 items per page)
        $data = $user->generates()->paginate(5);
        // Retrieve the "headers" relationship data for the user
        // $headersData = $user->headers; //only data related to the user in that current session available

        

        // Return the view 'obj.fillPDF' with the retrieved data as an associative array
        return view('obj.fillPDF', [
            'data' => $data,
            'headerData' => $headersData,
        ]);
    }

    public function edit(Generate $generate)
    {
        
        return view('obj.edit', ['generate' => $generate]);
    }


    //method for store, update, delete, celear all data, generate pdf
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'description' => ['required', 'string'],
            'image' => ['required', 'image'],
        ]);

        try {
            if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
                $image = $request->file('image');

                // Compress the image using Intervention Image library
                $compressedImage = Image::make($image)->orientate();
                $compressedImage->resize(400, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    $constraint->upsize();
                });
                $imageData = $compressedImage->encode('jpg', 75)->getEncoded();

                $user = Auth::user();
                $generate = new Generate([
                    'description' => $request->input('description'),
                    'image' => $imageData,
                ]);

                $user->generates()->save($generate);
            }

            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Display the error message and query details
            dd($e->getMessage(), $e->getTraceAsString());
        }
        return redirect(route('fillPDF'))->with('success1', 'Report data stored succesfully');
        
    }


    public function update(Request $request, Generate $generate)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'description' => ['required', 'string'],
            'image' => ['nullable', 'image'],
        ]);

        // try {
            $generate->description = $request->input('description');

            if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
                $image = $request->file('image');

                // Compress the image using Intervention Image library
                $compressedImage = Image::make($image)->orientate();
                $compressedImage->resize(400, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    $constraint->upsize();
                });
                $imageData = $compressedImage->encode('jpg', 75)->getEncoded();

                $generate->image = $imageData;
            }

            $generate->save();
            return redirect(route('fillPDF'))->with('success', 'Data updated succesfully');
            
        // } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //     // Display the error message and query details
        //     dd($e->getMessage(), $e->getTraceAsString());
        // }

        
    }


    public function delete(Generate $generate){
        try {
            $generate->delete();
            return redirect(route('fillPDF'))->with('success','Data deleted successfully');

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Display the error message and query details
            dd($e->getMessage(), $e->getTraceAsString());
        }
    }

    public function clearAllData()
    {
        // Clear all records from the generates table
        // Generate::truncate(); this one will truncate all data even when it is not theirs
        $user = Auth::user(); //only the auth user
        // Clear all records from the generates table for the current user
        $user->generates()->delete();

        return redirect(route('fillPDF'))->with('success', 'All data cleared successfully');
    }

//Method to store, and delete data into Header table
    public function headerStore(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'header_img' => ['required', 'image'],
        ]);

        try {
            if ($request->hasFile('header_img')) {
                $image = $request->file('header_img');

                // Compress the image using Intervention Image library
                $compressedImage = Image::make($image);
                $compressedImage->resize(400, null, function ($constraint) {
                    $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    $constraint->upsize();
                });
                $imageData = $compressedImage->encode('jpg', 75)->getEncoded();

                $user = Auth::user();
                $header = new Header([
                    
                    'header_img' => $imageData,
                ]);

                $user->headers()->save($header);
            }

            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Display the error message and query details
            dd($e->getMessage(), $e->getTraceAsString());
        }
        return redirect(route('fillPDF'))->with('success2', 'Header data stored succesfully');
        
    }

    public function headerDlt(Header $header){
        // try {
            $header->delete();
            return redirect(route('fillPDF'))->with('success3','Data deleted successfully');
        // } 
        // catch (\Exception $e) {
        //     // Display the error message and query details
        //     dd($e->getMessage(), $e->getTraceAsString());
        // }
        // return redirect(route('fillPDF'))->with('success3','Header data deleted successfully');
    }


public function generatePDF(Request $request)
{


    //retrieve data from generates table
    $user = Auth::user();
    $data = $user->generates;
    $titleCP = $request->input('titleCP'); // Retrieve the title for the cover page
    $title = $request->input('titleIR'); // Retrieve the title for the report content

    // Retrieve data from the Header table
    $headerData = Header::all();
    $headerImage2 = $headerData[1]->header_img;

    

    // Create a new TCPDF instance
    $pdf = new HeadNFoot(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    // Create a new TCPDF instance
    // $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    //create path to the image to public file
    $mtmlogo = public_path('logo/mtmlogo.png');
    $tnblogo = public_path('logo/Tenaga_Nasional.png');

    // Create a temporary file to store the image data
    // $tempImagePath = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'image');
    // file_put_contents($tempImagePath, $headerImage2); // $headerImage2 should contain the binary image data from the database
    
    
    //header data
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('MTM');
    $pdf->SetTitle('Site Supervision/ Transformer Services');
    $pdf->SetSubject('PICTURE REPORT');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, Maintenance, Service, Report');

    $pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', '', '');

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array('times', '', 12));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array('times', '', 12));
        
    // set default header data
    // $txt ='Site Supervision/, Transformer Sevice';
    // $txt = str_replace(', ', "\n", $txt); // Replace ', ' with a line break
    // $pdf->SetHeaderData('', 50, '', $txt);
    // $pdf->setFooterData(array(0,64,0), array(0,64,128));

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(10, 30, 10);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(20);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(40);
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true, 37); // Enable auto page breaks and set the bottom margin to 20 millimeters

    // Exclude the header for the cover page
    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(true);

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(3.5);

    // set JPEG quality
    $pdf->setJPEGQuality(75);

    // Add a page for the cover page
    $pdf->AddPage(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, false, 'UTF-8', false);

 //-------------------START COVER PAGE------------------------------//

    // Add the image to the PDF
    $pdf->Image($mtmlogo, 10, 20, 50,'', 'PNG', '', '', false, 300, 'C', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
    
     

    // Create the rest of your HTML content for the cover page
    $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 12);
    $pdf->setCellHeightRatio(2);

    //color for background
    $pdf->Ln(35);
    $pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);

    $txt = 'MALAYSIA TRANSFORMER MANUFACTURING SDN BHD, (31108W), (A Subsidiary of Tenaga Nasional Berhad)';
    $txt = str_replace(', ', "\n", $txt); // Replace ', ' with a line break
    $pdf->MultiCell('', '', ''.$txt, 0, 'C', 1, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 40, 'M');

    $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 16);
    $pdf->ln(55);
    // set cell padding
    $pdf->setCellPaddings(45, 0, 45, 0);
    $txt = $titleCP;
    $pdf->MultiCell('', '', ''.$titleCP, 0, 'C', 1, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 40, 'M');

    $pdf->setCellPaddings(0, 0, 0, 0);
    $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 12);
    $pdf->Ln(80);
    $txt = 'MALAYSIA TRANSFORMER MANUFACTURING SDN. BHD (31108-W), A SUBSIDIARY OF TENAGA NASIONAL BERHAD, LOT 22 JALAN AU 3/1 ULU KLANG, 54200 KUALA LUMPUR MALAYSIA.';
    $txt = str_replace(', ', "\n", $txt); // Replace ', ' with a line break
    $pdf->MultiCell('', '', ''.$txt, 0, 'C', 0, 0, '', '', true);

    // $pdf->Ln(50);
    // $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 10);
    // $txt = 'REPORT-TRANSFORMER SERVICE';
    // $txt = str_replace(', ', "\n", $txt); // Replace ', ' with a line break
    // $pdf->MultiCell('', '', ''.$txt, 0, 'L', 1, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 40, '');
 
    //-------------------END OF COVER PAGE------------------------------//
    
    //-------------------PICTURE TABLE-----------------------------------//

    // set font of the report
    $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 12);

    //set header print to true
    $pdf->SetPrintHeader(true);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(true);

    
    // Add a new page for the content of the report
    $pdf->AddPage(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
    
    // Include the header for subsequent pages (optional, you can customize this part as needed)
    

    $pdf->Cell(0, 10, $title, 0, 1, 'L');

   // Start the heredoc
   $html = <<<EOD
   
   <table border="1" nobr="false" cellpadding="20" >
   
   EOD;
   
 
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i += 3) {
       $html .= '<tr nobr="true">';
      
       for ($j = $i; $j < $i + 3; $j++) {
           if ($j < count($data)) {
               $item = $data[$j];
               $html .= '<td align="center">';
               $html .= '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($item->image) . '"  >';
               $html .= '</td>';
           } else {
               // Generate empty cells for any remaining spaces
               $html .= '<td></td>';
           }
       }
   
       $html .= '</tr>';
       
       $html .= '<tr nobr="true">';
       for ($j = $i; $j < $i + 3; $j++) {
           if ($j < count($data)) {
               $item = $data[$j];
   
               $html .= '<td align="center">';
               $html .= $item->description;
               $html .= '</td>';
           } else {
               $html .= '<td></td>';
           }
       }
       $html .= '</tr>';
   }
   
   $html .= '</table>';
   


    // Now you can add this HTML content to your TCPDF instance
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

    // Create a table for the content (you can reuse the table generation code from your original generatePDF function)


    //unlink picture
    // unlink($tempImagePath);
    // Output the generated combined PDF (stream or save)
    $pdf->Output($title, 'I');
}



}

    
class HeadNFoot extends TCPDF{
    //custom Page header
    public function Header() {
        // Logo
        $mtmlogo = public_path('logo/mtmlogo.png');
        $tnblogo = public_path('logo/Tenaga_Nasional.png');

        $this->Image($mtmlogo, 15, 10, 30, '', 'PNG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
        $this->Image($tnblogo, 90, 10, 30, '', 'PNG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('times', '', 12);
        $txt = 'Site Supervision/ , Transformer Services';
        $parts = explode(',',$txt);
        // Title
        $this->Ln(5);
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            $this->Cell(0, 0, $part, 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
            $this->Ln(5);
             // Move to the next line for the next part
    }
    }

     //custom Page footer
     public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('times', '', 10);
        //footer
        $this->Cell(0, 0, 'REPORT-TRANSFORMER SERVICE', 0, false, 'L', 0, '', 0, false, 'M', 'M');
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }
}
```

So, down here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "illuminate/pagination": "*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.7",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "laravel/ui": "^4.2",
        "nesbot/carbon": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php83": "*",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

I was trying to do the customize header and footer. Im using the method suggested by the TCPDF documentation. Mind that TCPDF works fine and had no problem at all when running locally(XAMPP), but when I uploaded it to the CPANEL it suddenly couldn't find the TCPDF class. I get "**Class "TCPDF" not found".

It highlights this line: **

```
class HeadNFoot extends TCPDF{} // on this line
```

Im sure that I've updated the composer.json on my cpanel file. and the cpanel php version is 8.1 and now I dont know what to fix. Please help me.

Comment: How did you install that dependency? How did you deploy it? Is this really a problem related to Laravel or cPanel itself?

Comment: I think I didnt manage to install it correctly, I THINK ITS MY PROBLEM :(  I think I deployed the laravel project wrong. Because, I redirect my cpanel terminal to my subdomain and the composer cannot find the composer.json file, eventho the composer.json file is in the subdomain directory. I dont know what to do, Im soooo new in web dev and web deployment

Comment: So, how did you deploy the project? Usually, you should not run any Composer command on the server, nor edit any files by hand

Comment: I followed a YouTube tutorial to deploy my Laravel project on a subdomain in cPanel. Initially, I zipped and uploaded the project successfully. However, when I tried to update it with a new zip file upload, it didn't work, and I couldn't find the best way to resolve the issue. Now, the tcpdf class is not found, but works locally.

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it, not to the comment section

Answer (score -1):

Run `composer install` on server, using terminal/ssh on your web root dir. When you upload the composer.json to the server doesn't mean the server will install the deps automatically, unless you're using automated deployment services.

Comment: hi, greetings @MaulanaKrniawan , I just upload the file. before this I did that and it works fine. Im new to website dev and new to deploying website on server. Prolly since I added new library TCPDF I need to run composer install. But ive tried to redirect my cpanel terminal to my directory, but it says it couldnt find the composer.json file while the file is in the directory. Could I be deploying my laravel project wrong since the first time.

Comment: Even if this would work: never run `composer install` on any server. Use a proper deployment process that installs all packages on a deployment machine, and deploy the resulting application (including your vendor folder)

Comment: @naqibjunaidy You may be missed a few dot files in deployment. Nico Haase Yes, that would be ideal. I guess I'm doing it wrong. Thanks.